# Parsing hex string command in C

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to to write a hexadecimal command into serial port, where i need to convert a hex string into particular byte array format in C, having problem with parsing escape character. please help to implement this below function. Thanks.

```
int hex2byte(char* write_buf)
{
    //code to parse this string into byte array removing escape character and keeping other special character as it is
    // resize str, In this case it resize strlen(str)=14 bytes into 5 bytes array; 
    // Goal is to Fill the str in this desired way
    //   write_buf = {0x02, 0x00, ';' ,';', 0x03};
    //      Or
    //  write_buf = {0x02, 0x00, 0x3b ,0x3b, 0x03};

    return size_of_write_buf;
}
```

Run ./serial -w "\x02\x00;;\x03"

> OUTPUT:
>   write_buf=\x02\x00;;\x03 size=14 
>   0x5c,0x78,0x30,0x32,0x5c,0x78,0x30,0x30,0x3b,0x3b,0x5c,0x78,0x30,0x33

Here The issue I am getting for option -w  write_buf = "\x02\x00;;\x03" getting total 14 bytes, but I need this data to be in 5 bytes e.g 0x02, 0x00, 0x3b ,0x3b, 0x03.

```
//serial.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>
int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    char *write_buf= NULL;
    int i;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "w:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt) {

            case 'w':
                write_buf = optarg;
                printf("write_buf=%s size=%ld \n", write_buf, strlen(write_buf));

                for(i=0; i<14; i++)
                    printf("0x%02x\n", write_buf[i]);

               /****Implement This function*****/

                /*  int size= hex2byte(write_buf);
                    for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
                    printf("0x%02x\n",write_buf[i]);  
                    Should print 0x02, 0x00, 0x3b ,0x3b, 0x03.
                */ 
                break;
        }
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That function doesn't make any sense... where's the actual code?

Comment: Hmm... the function returns `char*` but the returned value is saved in an int...

Comment: Also what do you mean with  "Desired output: 0x02 0x00 0x3b 0x3b 0x03". Simply print the ASCII values without parsing anything?

Comment: Further, `return size_of_array` suggest return of integer type which again conflicts with return type `char*`

Comment: And... the array already contain those values

Comment: Actually I am writing utility tool to write on serial port  command looks like      
   serial -p /dev/ttyS0 -b 115200  -w 'command'                                                     e.g  serial -p /dev/ttyS0 -b 115200 -w '\x02\x00;;\x03'   ,   -w stand for write

Comment: Yes ,  '\x02\x00;;\x03' coming as argv[6]

Comment: user3121023 Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

It seems you misunderstand what is in `str` to start with.

After

```
char* str ="\x02\x00;;\x03";
```

`str` points to a memory location where the following values are stored:

```
0x02 0x00 0x3B 0x3B 0x03 0x00
                         ^^^^
                         Zero termination
```

Exactly what you need. So you don't need a function to convert any data. The data already have the correct values.

Your problem is rather that you can't find the size because the `\x00` placed a termination in the middle of the string. There is no way to solve that using a `char*`. There is no way that the function `hex2byte(char* str)` can figure out that there is 5 bytes in your example.

You'll need a fixed size array or a hard coded size. But if you use a fixed size array or hard coded size, you don't need the function at all.

See https://ideone.com/bSUeOb for a running example